# Number of Voters Betting Pool

Tags: discussion

We can see how many people have voted in the Worldbuilding election by looking at the number of [Constituent](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/81/constituent) badges awarded.

This is a little friendly contest for no prize at all. Lets see who can post the number closest to the final number of constituents we have.

The rules are simple, post an answer or comment here before 12:00 UTC tomorrow with a guess of the number of Constituents we will have at the end of the election. You can't pick a number anyone else has chosen. The closest to the final number wins. <sub>One entry per person. The decision of the organizers is final. By taking part in this competition you sign over all rights to the color yellow and that story you wrote in English class when you were 7.</sub>

**Congratulations to Overactor and XandarTheZenon for the closest guesses. Have a virtual cookie :)**

The election site is saying 309, the badge count is 308. 309 means Overactor wins, 308 means Xander wins so I'm calling it a join win.

Comment: No! Not the color yellow! Also, I Worked really hard to write that paper about picking my puppy. It was a very emotional experience for my six year old brain.

Comment: @TimB joke's on you, I didn't have English class yet when I was 7.

Comment: @XandarTheZenon Unfortunately no rep on Meta, however if enough people upvote they may get a badge.

Comment: Well, then they get my free bragging rights. And maybe a sticker, oops, I meant badge.

Comment: I didn't write any story in English class when I was 7, because I didn't have any English class when I was 7.

Comment: No English in first grade in Norway either. But I am sorry for the loss of one of my favourite colours.

Comment: Since Overactor should have his nice answer badge now everyone can have their yellow back :)

Comment: Yay! Yellow is back!mToo bad I only got second place. Good job @overactor

Comment: What was the actual number of voters though? 309?

Comment: [308](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/81/constituent)

Comment: That doesn't make too much sense. Wouldn't @XandarTheZenon win? His guess was only 7off, while overactor's was 8.4 off.

Comment: @fi12 Good point, I was looking at the count on the election itself which is 309. That's differnet from the badge count

Comment: Oh, I won! Hooray! No badge though. Whatever :P It makes little difference. I enjoyed the guessing.

Comment: you should have had a bounty prize.

Answer (score 15):

My guess is **316.4**, since that's the id of this answer divided by 10.

Answer (score 5):

My guess is **301** It's a good number.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sticking with my big round number of **400**

Answer (score 0):

I say **347**. There's no reason for the choice whatsoever. It's probably a terrible guess. Nothing interesting even happened in all of 347 AD. But it's my choice.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go with 375.

I suppose time will tell.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go with **351**, possibly making for interesting interactions with HDE 226868's guess.  C'mon, 349!  Make the judge decide how to break ties!

Comment: We can squeeze HDE!

Answer (score 0):

346 Because that is what my RNG told me (randomnumber(339,350)).
It is also a [Franel number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FranelNumber.html)

Answer (score 0):

The glass is half empty, and the final number will be 300. I'll make the reservations in hell, we can all dine there tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

#### 327

No particular reason.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going for **320**, as I'm arriving late to the party and mercilessly exploiting the gaps left by everyone who has voted so far.

Answer (score 0):

I will go even higher: **404** voters, because internet

EDIT: Because I guessed too late, **I am not eligible to win**

Comment: https://xkcd.com/404/

Answer (score 0):

250 constituents voted in the last election.